# Serial communication in metro style app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, serial-communication

I am developing metro style app which should read data from external device using serial communication but unfortunately metro apps does not support **"Serial and parallel port API "**. So i thought to use **hyperterminal** to read data from serial port and use it in my metro application. Is there any way to access data directly from hyperterminal using c# in metro style app? If no is there any other way to access data from serial port in metro style app?

Comment: WinRT currently does not have support for Serial COM.  See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make this work with Hyperterminal either.  The sandbox in which Store apps operate explicitly defeats any attempt a Store app might make to use a inter-process communication mechanism.

Do ask yourself if it makes sense to publish such an application in the Store.  The odds that a user that visits the store will have the required hardware to make your app useful are extremely slim.  These kind of apps will stay desktop apps for a long time to come.  If the manufacturer of the device sees a market opportunity to get his device operating in store apps then he'll create a Store compatible driver for it.  But that's up to them, you cannot do this yourself.

Comment: Thank you for reply.We are developing app for competition purpose and the potential user of our application is only farmer. Actually the device is designed by our self and gives couple of binary data as output and we want them to capture in metro app. We are putting that binary data serial port and want to show that data in metro app. Is there a way to capture that data in to a file and then read that file from metro app?

Comment: Thank you for reply.We are developing app for competition purpose and the potential user of our application is only farmer. Actually the device is designed by our self and gives couple of binary data as output and we want them to capture in metro app. We are putting that binary data in to computer using rs232 and want to show that data in metro app. As far as i know it is not possible to get data directly to metro app from serial port, so is there any way in win8 to capture that data in to a metro app supported file(like xml) so that i can read that file from metro app to get data i want.

Comment: Well, sure, write the file to a location that a Store app has access to.  Like the Documents folder.  Use FilePicker to allow the user to select a file.  You are still ignoring the program distribution issue, it seems.